# Laravel: create a button that affect a column in my database

Tags: php, laravel

Is it possible to create a button that changes a `column` value in a table?
I have a `column` named `status` in my `movimentations` table, and I was wondering if it is possible to change  the value of this `column` with a button in my `view` that can change from active to inactive

this is my view

```
<div class="container">
    <label for="name" class="form-group"><b>Nome</b>: {{ $movs->nameCoop }}</label><br>
    <label for="name"><b>Numero</b>: {{ $movs->numCoop }}</label><br>
    <label for="name"><b>CPF</b>: {{ $movs->cpfCoop }}</label><br>
    <label for="name"><b>Cadastro</b>: {{ $movs->dtCad }}</label><br>
    <label for="name"><b>Demissão</b>: {{ $movs->dtDem }}</label><br>
    <label for="name"><b>Observações</b>: {{ $movs->description }}</label><br>
    <label for="name"><b>Subscritas</b>: {{ $movs->subscritas }}</label><br>
    <label for="name"><b>A integralizar</b>: {{ $movs->aintegralizar }}</label><br>
    <label for="name"><b>Integralizadas</b>: {{ $movs->integralizadas }}</label><br>
    <label for="name"><b>Status</b>: {{ $movs->status }}</label><br>
            <td>
                <form action="/trans" method="POST">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="input-group">
                      <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="r" value={{$cooperado->id}}>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                          <span>+</span>
                        </button>
                      </span>
                    </div>
                </form>
    </td>
    <td>
                <form action="/mvs" method="POST">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="input-group">
                      <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="v" value={{$cooperado->id}}>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                          <span>ver mvs</span>
                        </button>
                      </span>
                    </div>
                </form>
    </td>
```

this is my controller

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Cooperado;

class CooperadoController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
        //$cooperados = Cooperado::all();
        $cooperados = Cooperado::orderBy('dtCad', 'desc')->paginate(10);
        return view('cooperados.index', compact('cooperados'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
        return view('cooperados.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
        $request->validate([
            'nameCoop'=>'required',
            'numCoop'=> 'required|integer',
            'cpfCoop'=> 'required',
            'dtCad'=>'required|date',
            'subscritas'=>'required'
          ]);
          $cooperado = new Cooperado([
            'nameCoop' => $request->get('nameCoop'),
            'numCoop'=> $request->get('numCoop'),
            'cpfCoop'=> $request->get('cpfCoop'),
            'dtCad'=> $request->get('dtCad'),
            'description'=> $request->get('description'),
            'subscritas'=> $request->get('subscritas'),
            'aintegralizar'=> $request->get('subscritas'),
            'status'=> $request->get('status')
          ]);
          $cooperado->save();
          return redirect('/cooperados')->with('success', 'Cooperado adicionado');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
        $cooperado = Cooperado::find($id);
        return view('cooperados.show', compact('cooperado'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
        $cooperado = Cooperado::find($id);

        return view('cooperados.edit', compact('cooperado'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
        $request->validate([
            'nameCoop'=>'required',
            'numCoop'=> 'required|integer',
            'cpfCoop'=> 'required',
            'dtCad'=>'required|date',
            'subscritas'=>'required'
          ]);

          $cooperado = Cooperado::find($id);
          $cooperado->nameCoop = $request->get('nameCoop');
          $cooperado->numCoop = $request->get('numCoop');
          $cooperado->cpfCoop = $request->get('cpfCoop');
          $cooperado->dtCad = $request->get('dtCad');
          $cooperado->dtDem = $request->get('dtDem');
          $cooperado->description = $request->get('description');
          $cooperado->subscritas = $request->get('subscritas');
          $cooperado->integralizadas = $request->get('integralizadas');
          $cooperado->aintegralizar = $request->get('aintegralizar');
          $cooperado->status = $request->get('status');
          $cooperado->save();

          return redirect('/cooperados')->with('success', 'Cooperado atualizado');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    $cooperado = Cooperado::find($id);
    $cooperado->delete();

    return redirect('/cooperados')->with('success', 'Sucess');
    }
}
```

I've tried to create a function in my route, but didn't work.

Comment: what do you mean by "change my column", are you trying to change the value of a column or something else ? and add your controller method

Comment: yes, change the value in my column

Comment: okay, also add your routing code to get which method is calling on `"/trans"` and `"/mvs"` route

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added option button for `active` and `inactive`

```
<form action="/active-deactive" method="POST">
    @csrf
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="v" value="{{$cooperado->id}}">
            <select required class="form-control" id="status"  name="status">              
                <option value="1">Active</option>  
                <option value="0">De-Active</option>  
            </select>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
            <span>Confirm</span>
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**controller**

```
public function Confirm(Request $request)
{
    $id = $request->input('v');
    $status=$request->input('status');

    DB::table('tablename')
            ->where('id',$id)
            ->update(['status'=>$status]);

}
```

**route**

```
Route::post('/active-deactive','YourController@Confirm')
```

Comment: can i update more than a column in ` DB::table('tablename')->where('id',$id)->update(['status'=>$status]);`? like an 'and' statement?

Comment: yes! i dont really no what you want. anyway, if you want to update another column where the id. you can do DB::table('tablename')->where('id',$id)->update(['status'=>$status, 'sales'=>$sales]);

Comment: you can still use two or more where() clause like.  DB::table('tablename')->where('id',$id)->where('salesid',$sid)->where('purid',$pid)->update(['status'=>$status]);

Comment: Thank you samju, this helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can. You can send a request via ajax when clicking on that button:

```
$.ajax({
     type:'POST',
     url:'{{ route("NameOfYourRoute") }}',
     dataType:'json',
     data:{
         isActive = $('#theButtonID').val(),
         _token = '<?php echo csrf_token() ?>'
     },
     success:function(data){
         if (data.updated) {
             alert('Data Updated');
         }
     }
});
```

Then in your controller, you can have a function that receives the value of the button (active or inactive) and updated your table in the database:

```
public function toggleActivity(Request $request)
{
     $isActive = $request->get('isActive');
     $updated = Model::where(yourCriteria)->update(['isActive' => $isActive]);

     return view('YourView', compact('updated'));
}
```